# Maven on IntelliJ not working.

Tags: maven, intellij-14

Running

```
mvn -e clean install
```

on IntelliJ is throwing this error

```
Error running mvn: Cannot start process, the working directory /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin does not exist
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit configurations > Create a new Maven build. 
Choose the working directory to be the folder location of your project and not ".". This is something I was not doing.